# How to change the sending message "Please wait..." of the form button after it is already loaded?

Tags: mautic

I'm calling a Mautic form using its token instead of a manual copy.

```
{form = 5}
```

When the form is submitted, the button text temporarily changes to "Please wait ...".
However, I need it to be a different text.

If I implement the form by manual copy, I could modify this message just by declaring this variable.

```js
var MauticLang = {
  'submittingMessage': "Another text"
}
```

I tried this in a script within the HTML where the form is, after and before it, also after the DOM is loaded, but there was no effect. I investigated the code on the page as much as I could, but to no avail. I have researched, but can't find a solution anywhere.

How to change the button sending message after the form is already loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify `submittingMessage` value is the way to go.

```
MauticLang.submittingMessage = "Hold your horses...";
```

Or

```
MauticLang = {
  'submittingMessage': "Hold your horses..."
}
```

---

In addition, to ensure that you are modifying it after Mautic is loaded, you can use `setTimeOut` with load event listener on window.

Something like 5 seconds, enough time to have the form not fully filled by the user.
So, the final solution could be:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    MauticLang.submittingMessage = "Hold your horses..";
  }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: I had managed to solve the problem. That was basically it, I changed the value of `submittingMessage` (as I mentioned in the question as well). But it only worked after I changed it after a few seconds. That's why I edited your answer taking this into account.